# Saving images to device, and using a network image only if it isn't saved on the device (Flutter)

Tags: android, android-studio, flutter, dart

I am new to Flutter, so sorry if this is a silly question.

I am trying to make an app in which a user can upload an image (not necessarily an image, there should be an option to upload all kinds of files) and every time he enters the app it will be there (automatically).
So I implemented Firebase into the app, but that's a bit heavy on the user's network, especially if he's on a cellular connection, it might apply additional charges.

So I want to implement a functionality which automatically saves the loaded images to the user's internal storage, and next time it won't need to load it over, but, if the user does not have it on his storage it will load it again from the internet and save it.

Also I want the user to be able to delete it directly from his internal storage not necessarily through the app, but there should be an option in the app to delete it as well.

Example for the functionality I am looking for is Telegram, it has the images on the server and loads them only if they aren't saved on the device, and the user can easily go into his storage and delete the files saved.

My app's current functionality is loading the images into the app from their Firebase URLs every times the app is started.

My current code:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:firebase_storage/firebase_storage.dart';
import 'package:flutter/widgets.dart';
import 'dart:io';
import 'package:image_picker/image_picker.dart';
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
    
final _firestore = Firestore.instance;
int pictureNumber = 0;
Stream stream;

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      theme: ThemeData.dark(),
      home: MyHomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  @override
  void initState() {
    stream = _firestore.collection('links').orderBy('link').snapshots();
    super.initState();
  }

  var _scaffoldKey = GlobalKey<ScaffoldState>();
  String imageLink;
  File _image;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        backgroundColor: Colors.blue,
        child: Icon(
          Icons.add,
          size: 30,
        ),
        onPressed: () async {
          _image =
              // ignore: deprecated_member_use
              await ImagePicker.pickImage(source: ImageSource.gallery);

          FirebaseStorage firebaseStorage = FirebaseStorage.instance;
          StorageReference rootReference = firebaseStorage.ref();
          StorageReference pictureFolderRef =
              rootReference.child('pictures').child('$pictureNumber');
          pictureFolderRef.putFile(_image).onComplete.then((storageTask) async {
            String link = await storageTask.ref.getDownloadURL();
            await _firestore
                .collection('links')
                .add({'link': link, 'index': pictureNumber});
            setState(() {
              pictureNumber++;
            });
          });
        },
      ),
      key: _scaffoldKey,
      body: PictureStream(),
    );
  }
}

class PictureStream extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return StreamBuilder(
      stream: stream,
      // ignore: missing_return
      builder: (context, snapshot) {
        List<Widget> pictures = [];
        List<Widget> fPictures = [];
        if (!snapshot.hasData) {
          return Center(
            child: CircularProgressIndicator(
              backgroundColor: Color(0xFF3E3E3E),
            ),
          );
        }
        final links = snapshot.data.documents;
        for (var linkData in links) {
          final index = linkData.data['index'];
          final link = linkData.data['link'];
          print(link);
          print(index);

          pictures.add(Image.network(link));
          print(pictures.length);
          pictureNumber = pictures.length;
        }
        for (Image image in pictures) {
          fPictures.add(image);
          fPictures.add(Divider());
        }
        return Container(
          width: double.infinity,
          child: Column(
            children: [
              Expanded(
                  child: ListView.builder(
                itemCount: fPictures.length,
                itemBuilder: (context, index) => Padding(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
                  child: fPictures[index],
                ),
              )),
            ],
          ),
        );
      },
    );
  }
}
```

Firebase Storage: https://prnt.sc/u0c6mr.
Firebase Database: https://prnt.sc/u0c6rw.

Comment: Try this cache network image: https://pub.dev/packages/cached_network_image

Comment: How does this give me the functionality I need? How would I make this work with Firebase to make it re-download whatever images which aren't downloaded already?